# Send ether from web3 to fallback payable contract function

Tags: ether, truffle

I'm trying to send some Ether to the payable function of my contract and I'm unable to find/understand a resource to do so.

Here's my attempt below:

Web3 App file (simplified, without initialisation functions) :

```
App = {
  sendEther: function(_value) {

    // Enter details to send transaction;
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      var account = accounts[1]; // send from account index 1

      App.contracts.Plant.deployed().then(function(instance) {

        return instance.sendTransaction({ // Something like this?!
          from: account,
          gas: 5000,
          value: _value
        });
      }).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        return App.UpdateContractValues();
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

Simplified smart contract:

```
contract Plant {

    address public creator;

    uint public finney_balance; 

    function () payable public {
        finney_balance += msg.value/1000000000000000;
        depositedFunds(msg.value, finney_balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error/s are you getting with the code above?

Comment: `plantInstance.sendTransaction is not a function` which is expected as I wrote it as a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using truffle you can do it exactly as you wrote above:

```
instance.sendTransaction({
  from: account,
  gas: _gas,
  value: _value
}).then(function(result) {
  // 
});
```

Here's the truffle reference: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract#sending-ether--triggering-the-fallback-function

Comment: Does this work for payable function? Where do you mention what function is being called?